# How to handle Multitouch event in codenameone?

Tags: java, codenameone

I need to have a Multitouch event and I want to handle that in codenameone.
How is it possible to implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the versions of `pointerPressed/Released/Dragged` that accept an array as their argument. You can also override a pinch gesture specifically: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/in-a-pinch